# Specific question construction (couldn’t find anything on Google)

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, questions

How do I ask why a person does not want a certain thing ?
If *why don’t you* is more like a suggestion, and *why you don’t wanna…be together*, as far as I know, is grammatically incorrect, what’s the correct way to say it?**Why won’t you want to…** ??
*why do you not want to…*?

Comment: I don't understand the "..." between wanna and be together. Did you use "wanna" instead of "want to" for any reason? It would also be good to get an example with the whole question, not just the first few words of it.

Comment: *Why don't you...?* can also be a question, not just a suggestion.